# Working with unbind() and bind () function

Tags: jquery, click, bind, unbind

hi i've build an image slider with prev/next. The problem that after unbind the prev- or next Button, i want to bind them again, how can i integrate the bind() into my Code?

this is my Code:-

```
// for sliding right
var counter = 1;
$('#nextArrow').click(function(){
    var item_width = $('.productList li').width(); 
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.productList').css('left')) - item_width;
    $('.productList').animate({'left' : left_indent},function(){
        if( counter > $('.li_group').length - 1) {
            $('.nextArrow').addClass('disabled');
            $('.prevArrow').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#nextArrow').unbind('click');
        }
    });
    counter++;
});

// for sliding left
$('#prevArrow').click(function(){

    var item_width = $('.productList li').width();

    var left_indent = parseInt($('.productList').css('left')) + item_width;
    $('.productList').animate({'left' : left_indent},function(){
        if( counter == 1) {
            $('.prevArrow').addClass('disabled');
            $('.nextArrow').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#prevArrow').unbind('click');
        }
    });
    counter--;
});
```

Comment: Why are you bind pre/next button?

Comment: so the user after reaching the last image (right sliding) the next Buttun should be not firing click-event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `bind` or `unbind` at all. Add a class to your `#nextArrow` and `#prevArrow` elements and change your selector to only handle elements which do not have those classes using [**jQuery's `:not()` selector**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

For example, on your `#nextArrow` click handler, you could add this class to your `#nextArrow` element and ensure it's removed from your `#prevArrow` element:

```
if( counter > $('.li_group').length - 1) {
    $('#nextArrow').addClass('ignore-click');
    $('#prevArrow').removeClass('ignore-click');
    ...
}
```

Then you can modify your jQuery selectors to only affect elements which do not have the `ignore-click` class:

```
$('#nextArrow:not(.ignore-click)').click(...);

$('#prevArrow:not(.ignore-click)').click(...);
```